# Running a script before auto create tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate & postgresql, I want to run a script before hibernate create my tables based on entities

I am using this property in the applications.properties file, but It seems to be missing something, the script is not running

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files= classpath:schema.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. The assumption is that the scripts will populate the tables created during schema generation.

If you need to prepare the database, you need to do it before starting the session factory